# Add Entity to WCF Data Service using HttpWebRequest

Tags: silverlight, wcf, rest, httpwebrequest, wcf-data-services

Assuming i have a working WCF Data Service, how could i use the HttpWebRequest class to add a new entity to the exposed table ?

```
  HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://www.site.com/Website/Service1.svc/Users", UriKind.Absolute)) as HttpWebRequest;
  request.Method = "POST";
..... ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do is to using Silverlight [WCF Data Services client library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838234%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and try to access the service. 
You can then use Fiddler to see the request being sent and manually craft such requests using HttpWebRequest

Comment: I'm becomming sad to see that StackOverflow is becoming a "docummentation forum" instead of a "code forum". Man, please, let's show the code!